# some times description doesn't show in textview

Tags: ios, xml, textview

xml parsing link has sub tag as a link, in this link there is a description and images and title. I want to get the description part only then I wrote a code for that

```
- (void)loadingDescription
{
    NSError *error=nil;

    //* goshipsUrl has link and send to the nsdata*
    NSData *gossipshtmldata=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: gossipsUrl options:NSDataReadingUncached error:&error];
    // i am using the nserrer for which one is error,we need to find out but it gives no exceptions and nil value
   if (error) {
       NSLog(@"%@",[error localizedDescription]);
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"loading successfully");
}

TFHpple *gossipsParser = [TFHpple hppleWithHTMLData:gossipshtmldata];
NSString *gossipsXpathQueryString = @"//p//text()";

NSLog(@"%@",gossipsParser);//it has the object

descriptionGossipsNodes = [gossipsParser searchWithXPathQuery:gossipsXpathQueryString];
//in descriptionGossipsNodes has only 6 objects

if ([descriptionGossipsNodes count] > 0) 
{
    [self.emailButton setEnabled:YES];
    [self.twitterButton setEnabled:YES];
    [self.facebookButton setEnabled:YES];
    [scrollview setHidden:NO];
    NSMutableArray *tempArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (TFHppleElement *element in descriptionGossipsNodes) 
    {
        [tempArray addObject:[element content]];
    }
    //in temparary array has only <__NSArrayM 0x7f87e8dd1820>( , Contact us, , Privacy, © 2015,) this content.
    NSString *result = [tempArray componentsJoinedByString:@""];
    self.textview.text = result;
    }
    else
    {
        [self.emailButton setEnabled:NO];
        [self.twitterButton setEnabled:NO];
        [self.facebookButton setEnabled:NO];
        [scrollview setHidden:YES];

        UIAlertView *alert =[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Connection Failed" message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:  nil];

        [alert show];
    }
}
```

so how can I solve I explained the code in comments.

Comment: in temparray the tempArray and descriptionGossipsNodes is missing discription object data.description data not passing to the tempArray and descriptionGossipsNodes.

Comment: What is your **specific** problem? Text fields? XML parsing? What exactly? You shouldn't expect people here to help you if you just throw them a bunch of code.

Comment: gossipsUrl  has the full data.http://www.cinejosh.com/news-in-telugu/4/25143/rakhi-sawant-sunny-leone-bombay-fashion-show-kenada.html

Comment: @Deniel Rinser which is the xml parsing issue.a few links like above i didnt get the description and i will explain the problem in code and print the nslog values also.Please help me.

Comment: The point is, you need to express what your specific problem is, not just "this code doesn't work, why?". Looking at your code, your specific problem is related to XPath, right? So, why post all that code? Just post the relevant XML snippet and your current, non-working XPath query and what you expect it to do.

Comment: kk thank you for your suggetions @DanielRinser